# Can Flash AS3 listbox data contain variable info?

Tags: flash, listbox, actionscript-3

I'm populating a listbox like this:

```
dp.addItem( {label:"red dress", data:"OV4MP/23OL.swf"} );
```

Instead of data:"OV4MP/23OL.swf", I would like to make part of the data file name a variable from a dynamic textbox named centerPt that belongs to the parent movieclip, so I did this:

```
dp.addItem( {label:"red dress", data:"OV4MP/23"+MovieClip(parent.parent).centerPt.text+".swf"} );
```

When I trace the selectedItem.data using:
    trace("you have selected: "+ overlays.selectedItem.data);
    trace(MovieClip(parent.parent).centerPt.text);
I'm getting:
    you have selected: OV4MP/23.swf.  What I should get is OV4MP/23OL.swf. It is not picking up what is in the dynamic centerPt.text field which are the letters OL eventhough that text field is tracing correctly.

Is it possible that data can not hold a variable?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a variable in the array data of listbox, ie

```
dp.addItem( {label:"red dress", data:"chp"+MovieClip(parent.parent).centerPt.text+".swf"} );
```

I used a function in the CHANGE event to return the variable called theOverlay and included the label from the listbox (also now loading .png file instead of .swf):

```
dp.addItem( {label:"red dress"} );
var theOverlay:String;
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

myListbox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, getIt);
    function getIt(e:Event):void {
theOverlay = "chp/"+myListbox.selectedItem.label+MovieClip(parent.parent).centerPt.text+".png";   
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(theOverlay);
myLoader.load(myRequest);
```

}